# ¿Utilizar atributos "privados" en Python aumenta la seguridad de una aplicación web?

Tags: python, aplicación-web, seguridad, método, atributos

Aunque en Python todos los elementos dentro de una clase son públicos por default, existe una manera de emular un cierto grado de privacidad de los mismos usando dos guiones bajos al inicio del nombre del método o atributo, ej: `__contraseña`. Esto en realidad se limita a cambiar el nombre del atributo para evitar colisiones con los métodos internos de Python, como por ejemplo el método `__init__`, y para ello renombra el atributo añadiendo `_NombreClase` al inicio, de manera que el atributo que utilicé como ejemplo quedaría como `_NombreClase__contraseña`. Y si llamáramos al objeto por su atributo nos daría error, aunque seguiría siendo completamente accesible si hacemos la llamada usando el nombre que le viene asignado de forma automática como se ve en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
class MiClase:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__privada = "Mensaje secreto"
    
    def devuelve_privada(self):
        return print(self.__privada)

objeto = MiClase()

objeto.devuelve_privada()
#>> Mensaje secreto

print(objeto._MiClase__privada)
#>> Mensaje secreto

objeto.__privada
#>> AttributeError: 'MiClase' object has no attribute '__privada'
```

Debido a esto, pensaba que los atributos privados de una clase en Python tenían como único objetivo recordar o hacer notar a los desarrolladores implicados en un proyecto que dicho atributo no debe ser modificado a la ligera o que se debe utilizar un método específico de la clase para efectuar dicha modificación que realiza controles o validaciones de algún tipo sobre el nuevo valor a inserir. Pero luego me encontré con este código que he simplificado un poco para el ejemplo:

```
class Usuario:
    def __init__(self, usuario, contraseña):
        self.__nombreUsuario = usuario
        self.__contraseña = contraseña

    def set_contraseña(self, contraseña):
        self.__contraseña = contraseña

    def get_contraseña(self):
        return self.__contraseña
```

En este caso de la creación de un nuevo usuario, esta práctica es llevada a cabo en un contexto donde no se efectúa ningún tipo de validación (ya previamente hechas) y todo apunta a que es usado por razones de seguridad, y me preguntaba qué tipo de seguridad puede ofrecer esto. Debido a la vulnerabilidad antes expuesta, conociendo el nombre de la clase y del atributo se puede cambiar el valor del mismo. Tampoco entiendo muy bien por qué se deben crear medidas de seguridad para esto al interno de un código que gira en un servidor.

Siento que no estoy tomando en cuenta algo, porque quienes hicieron esto son programadores de mucha experiencia y estoy seguro de que deben tener una válida razón para ello.

Comment: Ya te han contestado acertadamente. Yo añadiría un comentario. Creo que quien ha escrito ese código lo ha hecho probablemente en la creencia de que ese mecanismo le mejorará la seguridad, tratando de imitar código Java o C++. Digo esto porque si quieres usar getters y setters python tiene otro mecanismo más pythónico: el decorador @property. En cualquier caso la utilidad de estas cosas es fundamentalmente para validación y nunca para impedir el acceso al atributo real que, como quedó claro, no es posible en python.

Comment: Por otro lado, el name mangling al final sólo sirve para complicar la depuración. Yo recomendaría nombrar los atributos "privados" con un solo underscore. Esto, **por convenio** significa que ese atributo no debe ser accedido directamente ya que es un atributo interno de la clase, y debe ser manipulado usando otros métodos (puede programarse una `property` para ello). En el caso del único underscore no se produce name mangling, lo que a la larga es mejor, proporcionando en el fondo el mismo nivel de "seguridad".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo estás tomando en cuenta todo y tu conocimiento es correcto.

Utilizar **dunderscore** (doble barra baja) en Python sirve para llamar a las normas del [**Name Mangling**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#:%7E:text=mangling%20%2D%20see%20above.-,Python,more%20than%20one%20trailing%20underscore.), que es exactamente el funcionamiento que has explicado tu al inicio con la clase `MiClase`.

Lo que hace es cambiar el atributo `__privada` por `_MiClase__privada`.

Sus únicos casos de uso como se indican en [PEP0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables) son:

- Para mejorar la lectura.
- Evitar conflictos de nombres en clases que han sido diseñadas para ser subclases.

En el caso de tu clase `Usuario` diría que las personas que lo han desarrollado lo han hecho con el objetivo de hacer los atributos "privados". Esto es una mala práctica en Python que se ve algunas veces, ya que como tú mismo has dicho no son privados.

Al no existir los métodos privados, lo único que puede hacer es dificultar el acceso a los métodos/atributos lo máximo posible. Pero **esto está completamente desaconsejado** lo único que hará será tu código menos legible.

Answer (score 6):

Vamos a partir del punto de que el uso de modificadores de acceso (`private`, `protected`, `public`), **no** responden a razones de seguridad para evitar que hackers, o personas no autorizadas, obtengan o alteren algún tipo de datos en ningún lenguaje.

Los modificadores de acceso cumplen un único propósito: Encapsulamiento. Su misión es hacer inaccesible los detalles internos de alguna clase, con el fin de evitar que otras entidades en nuestra base de código siquiera sepan de su existencia. Esto, con el fin de minimizar el coupling entre entidades.

Aún más, hay que recordar que el uso de getters y setters nada tiene que ver con encapsulamiento. De hecho, todo lo contrario: ellos atentan contra el correcto encapsulamiento de una clase ya que de igual manera exponen detalles internos de la misma. (Más información sobre esto puede encontrarse en este maravilloso artículo, de Allen Holub: https://www.infoworld.com/article/2073723/why-getter-and-setter-methods-are-evil.html)

Es decir si de alguien nos protegen los modificadores de acceso son de nosotros mismos y de nuestros propios compañeros de equipo, de que creen entidades dependientes de detalles, en lugar de dependientes de abstracciones e interfaces. Nada más.

En Python, ciertamente, no tenemos una manera de evitar el acceso o privatizar ciertos miembros de una clase. Acá nosotros nos fiamos de la (famosa) frase ["We are all consenting adults"](https://python-guide-chinese.readthedocs.io/zh_CN/latest/writing/style.html#we-are-all-consenting-adults). Básicamente, seguimos convenciones para hacer notar que ciertos miembros no deberían ser sobreescritos, alterados ni consumidos directamente. Sacrificamos esa estrictez del lenguaje, para permitirnos ciertas (aunque, en lo personal, incómodas) libertades. Puede gustar, puede que no, pero es el estilo de este gran lenguaje.

Finalmente, recordar que en lo que respecta a medidas de seguridad web, las medidas a tomar nada tienen que ver con este tema. Por ejemplo, en el caso de Django, estas medidas incluyen el guardar las contraseñas de manera encriptada, usar Cross Site Request Forgery Protection, usar un ORM para evitar cosas como SQL Injection, etc.

Comment: Muy buena aportación, Era un tema de fondo que nadie había tocado!

Answer (score 4):

> ¿Utilizar atributos “privados” en Python aumenta la seguridad de una
> aplicación web?

No necesariamente, o eventualmente sí. No, por que como ya lo has visto, no hay nada privado, al estilo de por ejemplo Java, por lo que cualquier programador "malvado" podría acceder directamente al atributo sin pasar por los "getters" o "setters". Eventualmente sí, si los programadores del proyecto respetan la convención de no uso de los atributos "privados", ya sea con guión bajo simple o con doble guión bajo.

Con respecto al código `set_contraseña()` y  `get_contraseña()`, ciertamente, al no tener ninguna validación y al no existir en Python el encapsulamiento "fuerte" que podríamos ver, por ejemplo en Java, es lógico preguntarse el sentido de estas funciones. Sin embargo, ciertamente puede existir patrones de diseño preestablecidos en el proyecto o en el equipo, que establezca "templates" básicos que incluya el uso de pseudo "getters" y/o "setters", también, que no existan validaciones hoy no significa que no las haya mañana, por lo que dejamos preparado el lugar para incorporarlas y por último, puede obedecer a necesidades reales del proyecto, que impliquen que ciertos atributos se accedan mediante este mecanismo.

Answer (score 3):

Acceder a los atributos privados de un objeto vía getter/setter tiene al menos dos beneficios.

El primero es la capacidad de *interceptar* los accesos a la variable. Como todos los accesos se hacen a través de setter/getter, tienes donde agregar *breakpoints* y *assert*.

Por ejemplo, digamos que en alguna parte de la aplicación alguien está cambiando la password por `None`. Con un setter, puedes poner un breakpoint condicional en la asignación:

```
def set_contraseña(self, contraseña):
    self.__contraseña = contraseña
```

de manera que la ejecución se interrumpa y puedas entrar con el depurador a mirar el stack de llamadas y los parámetros involucrados.

También puedes dejar un `assert` para detectar cualquier caso extraño:

```
def set_contraseña(self, contraseña):
    assert isinstance(contraseña, str)
    self.__contraseña = contraseña
```

La otra ventaja es la capacidad de hacer crecer la aplicación. Por ejemplo, ahora se puede agregar el requerimiento de que la nueva `password` debe ser distinta a la anterior.

Usando setters puedes imponer la restricción en toda la aplicación con sólo cambiar el setter:

```
def set_contraseña(self, contraseña):
    rc = True
    if contraseña != self.__contraseña:
        self.__contraseña = contraseña
    else:
        rc = False
    return rc
```

La función ahora retorna `True` si la contraseña pasó la validación y se actualizó.

Comment: Ya conocía ya esta aplicación pero tus ejemplos útiles y auto explicativos son un aporte válido al tema.

Comment: Es una buena explicación de por qué y cuando usar getters y setters, pero no explica por qué el atributo "privado" debería llamarse `__contraseña` en vez de `_contraseña` o incluso `contraseña` a secas. El double underscore no aporta seguridad extra, y sí complicaciones en la depuración debido al name mangling

Comment: @abulafia. Alberto Rubiales ya lo explico antes que yo; ¿para qué repetirlo?