# Qué sentido tiene la encapsulación de atributos de una clase si al final con un setter se puede modificar el valor desde afuera?

Tags: java, python, poo

No entiendo la razón de encapsular atributos de una clase. Por ejemplo en Java seria:

```
private variable;
public variable2;
```

o en python:

```
__variable
```

si al final se puede cambiar el valor con un setter

Comment: Un `setter` te permite interceptar cualquier cambio a la variable y tomar acciones como generar un log, validar el valor, etc.

Comment: Son herramientas para el programador precisamente para controlar la modificación de los atributos. No lo ves porque tu controlas todo el código. Imagina un proyecto grande de varios programadores y te contratan para hacer una GUI que recoge datos de la pantalla, pero no conoces el resto del desarrollo. El programador del núcleo te dará acceso a sus setters y getters para que puedas alimentar el sistema con entradas y salidas controladas, encapsulando el resto del código. No necesariamente necesitas saber qué hace el sistema, solo que tu parte funcione bien.

Comment: La encapsulación es uno de los conceptos fundamentales de la programación orientada a objetos (OOP). Describe la idea de agrupar información y restringirla solo a los métodos que necesitan trabajar con esa información (atributos). Estas restricciones a las variables y métodos pueden prevenir que modifiques accidentalmente la información de un objeto. Para prevenir estas modificaciones accidentales los atributos de un objeto solo pueden ser accesibles desde dentro de la clase con un método (pueden ser setter para asignar o setter para obtener la info). Aparte de todo es una buena practica.

Comment: En [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/415819/156415) aborto un poco el porqué del encapsulamiento y los modificadores de acceso. Es una duda común al empezar con POO.

Comment: Piensa en esto: "No entiendo la razón de poner puertas en las casas, si al final puedes llamar al timbre y te abren"

Comment: @abulafia: Una puerta sin cerradura, como un torniquete. ¿Los torniquetes son malos? Depende dónde y para qué los pongas.

Comment: @Sal Exactamente ese era mi punto. No estoy diciendo que la puerta sea mejor que la ausencia de puerta. Estoy diciendo que la pregunta sobre puertas es análoga a la pregunta sobre atributos privados. Y la respuesta es la que has dicho "Depende de dónde y para qué los pongas"

Answer (score 4):

Creo que esta es una de las preguntas que todos nos hicimos en su momento cuando nos iniciamos en la programación orientada a objetos y aunque en los comentarios ya te han respondido bastante bien, yo te voy a responder de la manera en que a mí me hubiera gustado que me la respondieran cuando tenía la misma inquietud.

Imagínate que creas una clase que será parte de un módulo, o mejor aún, de una librería que no solo usarás tú, sino muchísima gente en sus propios proyectos. Llamas a esta clase `Alumno` y tiene un atributo llamado `nombreCompleto`:

```
public class Alumno {
    public String nombreCompleto;
}
```

Si lo dejas así, podrás obtener y modificar el dato perfectamente sin ninguna restricción desde cualquier otra clase y eso es precisamente lo que necesitas, ¿entonces para qué un setter y un getter?

Ahora imagina que pasó 1 año y cada vez hay más gente que decidió usar tu librería, o en tu propio proyecto cada vez son más las clases que acceden a este dato. Un día por necesidades del negocio se decidió que el nombre del alumno se debería dividir y almacenar en dos propiedades llamadas `nombre` y `apellido`:

```
public class Alumno {
    public String nombre;
    public String apellido;
}
```

Al hacer ese cambio vas a generar errores de compilación porque la propiedad `nombreCompleto` ya no existe, con lo cual los usuarios de tu librería van a tener que tomar la decisión de no actualizarla o verse en la necesidad de tener que modificar todos los lugares donde se está usando el dato para adaptarse a la actualización y asumiendo los posibles problemas que las propias modificaciones puedan generar como daño colateral.

Ahora contrasta con una clase que aplique un correcto encapsulamiento:

```
public class Alumno {
    private String nombreCompleto;
    
    public String getNombreCompleto() {
        return nombreCompleto;
    }
    
    public void setNombreCompleto(String nombreCompleto) {
        this.nombreCompleto = nombreCompleto;
    }
}
```

Al hacer modificaciones podrías simplemente dividir la propiedad `nombreCompleto` en `nombre` y `apellido` sin cambiar el `signature` del getter y del setter. Así no rompes compatibilidades y no tendrás que hacer todas las modificaciones que de la otra manera habrías tenido que hacer:

```
public class Alumno {
    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;

    public String getNombreCompleto() {
        return nombre  + " " + apellido;
    }

    public void setNombreCompleto(String nombreCompleto) {
        String[] nombreApellido = nombreCompleto.split(" ");
        this.nombre = nombreApellido[0];
        this.apellido = nombreApellido[1];
    }
}
```

Hay mucho camino recorrido en la programación y existen patrones de diseño y mucha documentación sobre las buenas y malas prácticas. Todo tiene una razón de ser, sobre todo si son prácticas que se han aplicado por tanto tiempo y que aún se aplican. Te sugiero leer mucho y ojalá nunca te detengas, al final de cuentas nuestra calidad como desarrolladores siempre estará sujeta al nivel de conocimiento y experiencia que tengamos.

Answer (score 1):

El concepto de encapsulamiento no tiene que ver con el hecho de que la información no pueda cambiarse desde fuera de la clase –poco útil sería si a ningún objeto se le pudiera cambiar nada–, sino al hecho de que tenemos *control* de qué puede modificarse y qué no, y para lo que si se puede cambiar podemos tomar acciones, por un lado, para prevenir cambios inválidos y, por otro, para provocar *efectos secundarios* de manera controlada.

Los beneficios de esto son:

### Control de qué cambia y qué no

Una clase puede mantener tantas *cosas* como quiera en su parte privada, protegida o pública y de esta manera controlar quién tiene acceso a qué partes de cada instancia que se crea (y a cuales no), esto es esencial para lograr el siguiente beneficio.

### Encapsulamiento como ocultación

Además, podemos *ocultar* la manera en la que trabaja un objeto en particular tras bambalinas. Esta *ocultación* no tiene tanto que ver con mantener en la ignorancia a los usuarios de un objeto ni de mantener en secreto los detalles de como opera un objeto, sino más bien, en que los otros objetos no tienen por qué preocuparse u ocuparse de cómo otro objeto mantiene su estado o realiza sus funciones. Sabe que si se comunica de manera correcta a través de la parte pública de un objeto, este realizará su *trabajo* y no hay de que preocuparse. A esto se le llama *cumplir el contrato*.

Esto es particularmente importante cuando un sistema está en evolución (la mayoría de los sistemas que SI se usan están en constante evolución.

Usemos una analogía, de las tontas, pero que sirven para explicarse con ejemplos:

Imagina un objeto `CajeroAutomatico`, que tiene un método para sacar efectivo. En su version 1, el cajero internamente emplea a un objeto `Persona`, que es la encargada de procesar la petición y poner el dinero en la bandeja.

A medida que el sistema evoluciona, el programador de `CajeroAutomatico` decide ir cambiando su funcionamiento interno, de pronto está creando un complejo de instancias de `ServoMotor`, `Faja`, `Transistor`, etc.) y, en su versión 5, todo el funcionamiento interno del aparato es de última generación.

El resto del sistema se ha visto beneficiado de estos cambios, pero no ha tenido que re-escribirse, en cuanto se ha logrado mantener intacta la parte pública del objeto y el método `SacarEfectivo` sigue haciendo su trabajo como siempre. En otras palabras, el objeto *encapsula* la funcionalidad y el resto no tiene dependencias hacia esos mecanismos (si has escrito programas sin el paradigma orientado a objetos, entenderás a lo que me refeiero).

### Validaciones

Una de las ideas principales que ha dado lugar a la existencia de los *setters* es poder realizar validaciones de los valores que se le están asignando a un miembro de la clase y de esta manera mantener la consistencia de las instancias en memoria, imagina este *setter* de la edad de una persona:

```
public class Persona {
  private Integer edad;

  public void setEdad(Integer value) {
    if (value < 0) throw new EdadInvalidaException();
    this.edad = value;
  }
```

### *Efectos secundarios* controlados

La otra utilidad principal de los *setters* es poder ejecutar código adicional cuando se cambia el valor de un miembro de la clase.

El primer ejemplo que me viene a la mente es en aquellas clases que representan *recursos* del sistema, tal como un archivo, un *socket* o una conexión a bases de datos.

De nuevo, un (tonto) caso hipotético, que sirve para poner el ejemplo:

```
public class SocketCliente {
  private Integer puerto;
  private String host;
  //etcetera
  private boolean activo;


  public void abrir() {
    //abre la conexión...
    //acá va el código para gestionar el recurso en el sistema operativo...
    xxxxx();
    //finalmente, si todo tiene éxito establece el atributo activo a true
    activo = true;
  }

  public void cerrar() {
    //cierra la conexión...
    //acá va el código para gestionar el recurso en el sistema operativo...
    yyyy();
    //finalmente, si todo tiene éxito establece el atributo activo a false
    activo = false;
  }

  public void setActivo(boolean value) {
    if (value != activo) {
      if value abrir() else cerrar();
    }
  }
```

En esta clase, le permitimos al usuario llamar a los métodos `abrir()` y `cerrar()`, pero también soportamos que asigne *directamente* el valor de `activo`, mediante su *setter*:

```
   SocketCliente conexion = new SocketCliente('es.StackOverflow.com', 80);
   conexion.setActivo(true); //abre la conexión
```

Al hacer esto, provoca que la conexión se abra (un *efecto secundario*), y solo si esto tiene éxito el valor de `activo` cambiará efectivamente a `true`.

Quizás parece irrelevante, pero la clase ofrece *flexibilidad* de uso de esta manera. Hay muchísimos ejemplos en la vida real que tiran de esto, no solo para ofrecer *comodidad* o *flexibilidad*.

Answer (score 0):

Es sencillo, porque setter, por convención, es el nombre que se le dan a los métodos que modifican el estado de un objeto. Por lo general, es buen habito no programar los setter.

Segun wikipedia:

> En programación modular, y más específicamente en programación orientada a objetos, se denomina encapsulamiento al ocultamiento del estado, es decir, de los datos miembro de un objeto de manera que solo se pueda cambiar mediante las operaciones definidas para ese objeto.

Otra definicion:

> Decimos que el encapsulamiento en la programación orientada a objetos es cuando limitamos el acceso o damos un acceso restringido de una propiedad a los elementos que necesita un miembro y no a ninguno más.
> El elemento más común de encapsulamiento son las clases, donde encapsulamos y englobamos tanto métodos como propiedades.
> Otro ejemplo muy común de encapsulamiento son los getters y setters de las propiedades dentro de una clase. Por defecto nos dan el valor “normal” pero podemos modificarlos para que cambie.

Tu afirmación es correcta, con los setter podes modificar los atributos, es mas, vos mismo te estas respondiendo. Necesitas de un Setter para modificar el valor de un atributo, en esto consiste el encapsulamiento, que dependas de un método para modificar el atributo.

Ejemplo:

Tenes la clase persona

```
Public class Persona
{
   private String nombre;
   public int edad;
   
   public void setNombre(String nombre)
   {
      this.nombre = nombre;
   }
}
```

Ahora en el main

```
Persona p = new Persona();
p.setNombre("Juan");//atributo encapsulado, necesitas del método para modificarlo.
p.edad = 21;// como ves acá no necesitas de ningún método, le asignas el valor que vos quieras al objeto sin llamar a ningún método.
```

Espero haber sido claro en la explicación, si tenes alguna duda con mi respuesta solo consulta.